# Xslt find if element with id exists and copy to new location

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create an xslt file so I can find an element which references other elements within an area of my xml file and if that exists I want to replace the reference to the data directly with the data.

So going from:

```
<school>
    <People>
        <teacher Id="1">
            <name>Bill</name>
        </teacher>  
        <teacher Id="2">
            <name>Peter</name>
        </teacher>
    </People>
    <Courses>
        <Course>
            <name>Maths</name>
            <teacher Ref="1"/>
        </Course>
        <Course>
            <name>English</name>
            <teacher Ref="3"/>
        </Course>
        <People>
            <teacher Id="1">
                <name>Bill</name>
            </teacher>  
            <teacher Id="2">
                <name>Peter</name>
            </teacher>
            <teacher Id="3">
                <name>Jill</name>
            </teacher>
        </People>
    </Courses>  
</school>
```

to

```
<school>
    <People>
        <teacher Id="1">
            <name>Bill</name>
        </teacher>  
        <teacher Id="2">
            <name>Peter</name>
        </teacher>
    </People>
    <Courses>
        <Course>
            <name>Maths</name>
            <teacher Ref="1"/>
        </Course>
        <Course>
            <name>English</name>
            <teacher Id="3">
                <name>Jill</name>
            </teacher>
        </Course>
        <People>
            <teacher Id="1">
                <name>Bill</name>
            </teacher>  
            <teacher Id="2">
                <name>Peter</name>
            </teacher>
            <teacher Id="3">
                <name>Jill</name>
            </teacher>
        </People>
    </Courses>  
</school>
```

So you basically the following course is updated to:

```
<Course>
    <name>English</name>
    <teacher Id="3">
        <name>Jill</name>
    </teacher>
</Course>
```

I'm basically trying to fix data issues with xml but I'm struggling to figure this out using xslt. My example is simplified but the principal is the same.

Comment: Why is English updated with the name of the teacher, but Math isn't? And which group of People is the name supposed to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to William Walseth's answer, but uses an [`xsl:key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key) insead.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="teachers" match="teacher" use="@Id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="teacher[@Ref]">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="@Ref"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//teacher[count(.|key('teachers',$ref)[1])=1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- You have duplicate `teacher` elements (`@Id` value matches another `teacher/@Id`). This answer will use the first occurrence of `teacher` with the matching `Id` attribute.
- I assumed that you meant to update the "Maths" course.

Working example: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYis

Comment: Thanks Daniel and William. Both answers helped me out.

Comment: That xsltransform.net site is great btw

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It's a little weird that you've got the same teacher defined twice but the [1] selects the first match.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name='teachers' select='//teacher'/>

<xsl:template match="Course/teacher">
    <xsl:variable name='id' select='@Ref'/>
    <xsl:variable name='teacher' select='$teachers[@Id=$id][1]'/>
    <xsl:copy-of select='$teacher'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```